# I'm unable to install opencv-contrib-python in docker

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I tried installing **opencv-contrib-python** but I'm unable to get it to work on docker. It says  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python**

I tried,

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Then, I tired 
https://github.com/cassiobotaro/docker-opencv-contrib/blob/master/Dockerfile
 and I also tried,

```
    FROM python:3.5-alpine

    COPY . /app
    WORKDIR /app


    RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
    RUN apk add --no-cache git build-base musl-dev alpine-sdk cmake clang clang-dev make gcc g++ libc-dev linux-headers

    RUN mkdir /tmp/opencv
    WORKDIR /tmp/opencv
    RUN wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip
    RUN unzip opencv.zip
    RUN wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.1.zip
    RUN unzip opencv_contrib.zip
    RUN mkdir /tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.1/build

    WORKDIR /tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.1/build
    RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF ..
    RUN make -j4
    RUN make install

    RUN rm -rf /tmp/opencv


    RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["app.py"]
```

But I cannot get either one of it to work. PLease let me know how can I install the above in docker by just the requirements file?

More references (Things that I've tried) :
[Unable to install/run docker with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350876/unable-to-install-run-docker-with-opencv)

and

[from .cv2 import * ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359649/from-cv2-import-importerror-libgthread-2-0-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-f)

Comment: Have you tried any solutions that google suggests when you google that error? I get quite a few hits about people on alpine that are getting that error.
Namely https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/75

Comment: in your custom-built image (not the github one), which base image are you using? I've been using python 3.6-slim and 3.5-slim with no issues. Also, what's going wrong with the github image?

Comment: @C.Nivs Hi Nivs. I tried 3.5-slim and it has installed the libraries but I get any error while running docker. **Error: ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Comment: @C.Nivs I get this error when I run github docker image :

Comment: @C.Nivs E: Unable to locate package libjasper-dev
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential     cmake     wget     git     unzip     yasm     pkg-config     libjpeg-dev     libtiff-dev     libjasper-dev     libpng-dev     libavcodec-dev     libavformat-dev     libswscale-dev     libv4l-dev     libatlas-base-dev     gfortran     libtbb2     libtbb-dev     libpq-dev     && apt-get -y clean all     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My guess is that you're seeing the failure on the `-alpine` version because the `opencv` package is a binary distribution (it's not just Python code), and it probably hasn't been built for Alpine.  Alpine uses a C library that is different from everything else (Alpine uses MUSL libc while just about everthing else uses Glibc); there is some possibility that the opencv codebase won't even build for MUSL. Or maybe it's just that nobody has gotten around to building a binary package. In either case, you're better off with one of the following options:

If I use the stock python:3.5 image (not the Alpine one) it Just Works:

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:3.5 bash
root@95c81040aeaf:/# pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
Collecting opencv-contrib-python-headless
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/50/2427b286652cf64ea3618d08bfba38c04b6571f6f2c054e950367a2f309f/opencv_contrib_python_headless-3.4.3.18-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 24.1MB 2.4MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.11.1 (from opencv-contrib-python-headless)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/04/bd774106ae0ae1ada68c67efe89f1a16b2aa373cc2db15d974002a9f136d/numpy-1.15.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.8MB 4.7MB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-contrib-python-headless
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4 opencv-contrib-python-headless-3.4.3.18
root@95c81040aeaf:/# python
Python 3.5.6 (default, Nov 16 2018, 22:45:03)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

If I use the `3.5-slim` tag, I see the same error you reported:

```
root@63dca11a527f:/# python
Python 3.5.5 (default, May  5 2018, 03:17:29)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

As we can see from a [package query](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=stretch&section=all&arch=i386&searchon=contents&keywords=libgthread-2.0.so.0), that library is owned by the `libglib2.0-0` package, which is apparently not installed by default in the `-slim` version of the Python image.  We can fix that:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get -y install libglib2.0-0
```

And now it runs as expected:

```
root@63dca11a527f:/# python
Python 3.5.5 (default, May  5 2018, 03:17:29)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

You could build your own image incorporating this fix using a
`Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM python:3.5-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libglib2.0-0; apt-get clean
RUN pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

**Update**

Regarding your comment: if you want a package to be available to code
running in your container then, yes, you have to install it. Where
else will it come from?

If `opencv-contrib-python-headless` is included in your
`requirements.txt`, then what have posted in the comments should work
just fine:

```
FROM python:3.5
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

If you `requirements.txt` does not include this (why not?), you would
need to explicitly install it:

```
FROM python:3.5
RUN pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: I've shown every single command I ran here in this answer. What code are you asking for?

Comment: Sorry larks but I'm very new to docker and I'm trying different variations  in dockerfile to get this module to work but it always crashes out. The current code in my docker file looks like this :  **FROM python:3.5
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]**

Comment: DO I need install opencv as a command on the same image or something??

Comment: SOrry I'm totally noob here!

Comment: OK!!! It is running now and it displays **Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)** BUT when I open this link it shows **This page isn’t working**

Comment: PLease help me!!

Comment: I think you probably want to open a new question on that issue; the comments here aren't really the place for extended off-topic discussion. You would want to include whatever code in `app.py` is responsible for starting your service.

Comment: Not `libglib2.0`, `libglib2.0-0`. `libglib2.0` contains a dot, so `apt` considers it a regexp, and you end up installing more packages then you need.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I was using python-slim. It occurs due to run time dependencies. Add the following code snippet in your DockerFile to install run time dependencies.

## Install OpenCV's runtime dependencies

RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get -y install libglib2.0-0 RUN apt-get -y install libsm6 \ libxrender-dev \ libxext6