# from .cv2 import * ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I get this error when execute docker file for opencv:

**Error:**

```
from .cv2 import * ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
opencv-contrib-python-headless==3.4.3.18
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==0.6.1
cycler==0.10.0
dask==0.20.1
decorator==4.3.0
Flask==1.0.2
imutils==0.5.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
kiwisolver==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
networkx==2.2
numpy==1.15.4
Pillow==5.3.0
pyparsing==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.7.5
PyWavelets==1.0.1
scikit-image==0.14.1
scipy==1.1.0
six==1.11.0
toolz==0.9.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Why is there a dot before cv2 in import? `from cv2 import *` and not `from .cv2 import *`

Comment: @Vishnudev THat's an interesting Q. It's within the init file

Comment: from .cv2 import *
from .data import *

# wildcard import above does not import "private" variables like __version__
# this makes them available
globals().update(importlib.import_module('cv2.cv2').__dict__)

Comment: Oh okay. This is a new thing to learn. Cool.

Comment: But you are right! THat's the error! How can I run it without/updating the init file??

Comment: Could you try using the `-m` option provided by python to run the code? `python3 -m app.py` If you are expecting it to behave as a module rather than a single script

Comment: I did this : CMD ["python3 -m app.py"]

Comment: I got this error : python3: can't open file 'python3 -m app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Should be `CMD ["app.py", "-m"]` or `CMD ["python3", "-m", "app.py"]`

Comment: I tried the above command : **CMD ["python3", "-m", "app.py"]** and i got this error **(null): can't open file 'python3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Comment: Y am I getting this error?

Comment: because your working directory is /app you need to be in python interpreter location to run script using python

Comment: I did not get what u meant. Can you write down the code for the same.

Comment: apt-get install libglib2.0-0

Comment: `apt-get install libglib2.0-0` didn't work. `apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev` worked for me.

Comment: `apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev -y` worked for me, since I have included this code in the dockerfile.